# Error on Synaptic Reload

Tags: repository, synaptic, medibuntu

```
Error on Reloading Synaptic Package Manager. 
"Could not download all repository indexes." 
Problem with Medibuntu repositories. something wicked happened.
```

How do i resolve this?

```
"Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/free/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)"
```

Comment: Go to Softwares & Updates > Other Software (tab) > Untick ppa:medibuntu. Then reload. Do you see the error now?

Answer (score 0):

Medibuntu PPA has been shutdown, that's why synaptic failed to fetch the repository list from medibuntu. You need to remove that PPA or find another repository that provides packages from Medibuntu.

More details here, and some suggestions from the community : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu